# Custom .NET Attribute to Check Method Return Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, custom-attributes

At my company we use MVC.NET and Entity Framework to perform a SQL connection.  I was wondering if there is a way to create a custom attribute on a class that will create warnings if the return type of a method is not IEnumberable?  The idea is to avoid the developers defaulting to a collection making the function less generic.

Comment: Can you make your question a little clearer? What does *"defaulting to a collection making the function less generic"* mean?

Comment: How is the method related to the class that you want to decorate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net attributes are evaluated at runtime, and would not be useful for giving warning as the developers are churning out code. You can probably look at static analysis tools like FxCop / StyleCop so that these warnings are shown during compile time. In your particular case you might have to write a Custom Rule which will make the check.

Comment: +1 I was just writing an answer saying exactly the same thing!  (guess I missed out there).  To add to this here is a link to how to write just such a rule:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx - I think doing so would be more appropriate for what you want to do (although it may be quite hard to implement fully - i.e. checking that returning IEnumerable<T> is actually valid - worth a little investigation though I would say).

Answer (score 0):

Write a unit test checking the return type, rather than an attribute or anything else. That way you wont uglify your code.